# bind DataSource gridview + datatable to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I use asp.net and have `gridview`  control in aspx page. this gridview has not empty.

I have table name in page and want bind table to gridview. so:

```
gvName.DataSource =  dtName;
gvName.DataBind();
```

But with this code, Lost previous data in gridview. I went bind `gvName.DataSource + dtName` to `gvName`.

Comment: You have a two datasource and you want to combine them, after you want to set as datasource to `gvName` right ?

Comment: i have gvName (gridview), this not empty, so i have combine gvName and dtName (datatable) and bind this to gvName.

Comment: What is your gvName default datasource?

Comment: datasource gvName has bind from database, but i not want combine database and datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to combine the rows on both data tables (the original source and the new data table) and then rebind the new data table containing all the rows.

In pseudo code:

```
DataTable t = GetInitialDataSource();
foreach(var item in newDataTable.Rows)
{
    t.ImportRow(item); 
}

gv.DataSource=t;
gv.DataBind();
```

Comment: i want combine datasource and datatable no two datatable.

Comment: If it's not of type DataTable how do you expect to combine it if they are different? If they are different, then you need to create an entirely new object with the common fields and again, rebind the data. You cannot call gv.DataSource after a postback because it will be NULL.

Comment: can i insert to dtName.Rows with gvName.Rows...? please help me. i want not Lost previous data in gridview.

Comment: @AhmadRezaye no, you can't. Those are 2 different objects that have Rows of very different type. The best approach is to combine the 2 datatables and rebind the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. DataTable.Merge cab be used to combines the datatables.

```
    dtName.Merge((DataTable)gvName.DataSource);
    gvName.DataSource = dtName;
    gvName.DataBind();
```

Comment: its not ok. gvName.DataSource is null after a postback page.